Nullable Generic Typing
I'm getting some unexpected results when using the nullable reference types feature with generics.
For example, a generic class which has a nullable member
public class Entry<T> where T : notnull
{
    public T? Member { get; set; }
    
}

If I try to assign a nullable int to Member
Entry<int> integers = new();

int? nullNumber = null;

integers.Member = nullNumber;

I get the exception:
Cannot convert source type 'System.Nullable<int>' to target type 'int'

I expect the types of int? of the nullNumber and int? Member of the Entry to be the same.
Why does the compiler think they are different?

If you have this class declaration:
public class Entry<T> where T: notnull
{
    public T Member { get; set; }   
}

then the generated code will look like this (according to SharpLab):
[NullableContext(1)]
[Nullable(0)]
public class Entry<T>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private T <Member>k__BackingField;

    public T Member
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Member>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <Member>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}

And when you define your class like below:
public class Entry<T> where T: notnull
{
    public T? Member { get; set; }   
}

then the generated code will look like this:
[NullableContext(2)]
[Nullable(0)]
public class Entry<[Nullable(1)] T>
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
    private T <Member>k__BackingField;

    public T Member
    {
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <Member>k__BackingField;
        }
        [CompilerGenerated]
        set
        {
            <Member>k__BackingField = value;
        }
    }
}

Your Member's type is T. That means in your code integers.Member is int not int?.

If you want to make your code compile then change the constraint from notnull to struct. With that the Member will be Nullable<T>.

I assume that if I change the T to inherit from struct I will no longer be able to put objects inside Entry.

@user1239299 Yes that's correct. I'm unaware of any C# feature or attribute which would allow you to declare Entity<int> or Entity<string> and in both cases the Member is nullable.

It feels like this feature is incomplete

In generics, when T is unconstrained with struct or class then T? means "can have its default value".
So in your example, Member is defined as an int that can have its default value (i.e. does not need to be initialised by a constructor or init property).
You would need to declare integers as Entry<int?> integers = new(); to get the behaviour you want.
Also note that you will get the same compile error if you remove  where T : notnull.
See here for more details: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/7609
